# Overwrite the default Windows 10 style for xaml ui elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I´ve tried to change the `IsMouseOver` & `IsFocused` `BorderBrush` of a `TextBox`. 
But it seems not to take affect, I always get this ugly standart blue color.

My style is inside a `ResourceDictionary`.
It´s working perfectly fine, except the problem with changing the `BorderBrush`.

```
  <Style x:Key="TextBoxA" TargetType="TextBox" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF0E6D2"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF785A28"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000306"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF040B11" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF11171B" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF785A28" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC8C36E" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF785A28"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `ControlTemplate`. Right-click on the `TextBox` in design mode in Visual Studio and choose `Edit Template`->`Edit a Copy` to copy the default template into your XAML markup and then edit it as per your requirements:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF0E6D2"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF785A28"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000306"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF785A28"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF040B11" Offset="1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF11171B" Offset="0"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF785A28" Offset="1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC8C36E" Offset="0"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Okay, after putting your code as Style inside my ResourceDictionary and applying it to a TextBox Element, the Element just becomes invisible. Any advice on what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to copy my code as-is into a new window? Try to change the background to "Yellow" or something.

Comment: Ah, my fault... after Edit Template->Edit a Copy Visual Studio automaticly added a Template Binding to my TextBox Element and removed my Style Binding. Anyways, it seems to work now, but the MouseOver and IsKeyboardFocused BorderBrush Styles do not get applied.

Comment: Well, I don´t know where the problem was but since a restart of Visual Studio the MouseOver Triggers etc. are working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you edit the template of the control, you are pretty limited in what you can change. Here is the default template for the WPF TextBox, so change it to fit your desired style: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates